# How to embed OOTB web part in a user control?

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, user-controls

I'm planning to create a Visual Web Part. In the Visual Web Part's user control, I plan to embed an OOTB XSLTListViewWebPart, preferably through a declarative manner (in the .ascx). Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

goto ascx, add this reference:

for sharepoint 2010:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

for sharepoint 2013

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

now within the same aspx file below the refrences you can add:

```
<div id="customWebPartXSLT">

     <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" 

         ListUrl="Lists/myCustomList" 

         IsIncluded="True" 

         PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" 

         Default="False" 

         ViewContentTypeId="0x" >

     </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>  

</div>
```

You need to change the list url to the name of your list, my example list is called myCustomList!

Comment: Thanks ali Sharepoint! I edited the code to remove the "<WebPartPages:WebPartZone ..> tag" because when the tag is there, the user control throws the error "Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone' does not have a public property named '{web part name}'." It is a known error discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7740935e-d4d7-46f8-9dac-09b9c46855c6/type-microsoftsharepointwebpartpageswebpartzone-does-not-have-a-public-property-named-webpart?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy).